# Using boto3 as a base class

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3, botocore

With boto2, I could write a class that extended.
Say S3, with some custom functions but still allowed me to use any of the built-in ones.
Something like:

```
class MyS3(S3Connection):
    def bucket_exists(self, bucket_name):
        . . .


s3_connection = MyS3()
s3_connection.create_bucket('mybucket')  # built-in function
s3_connection.bucket_exists('mybucket')  # custom
```

But, in boto3, all of the resource/client classes are generated at runtime so I can't inherit directly.

I found the documentation on [extending boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/events.html) but I don't know, how one could subclass it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, true. You can`t directly extend any class, instead you could inject your Class functions, that will eventually gets called in Hierarchical order, means grand child first, then child, then parent like that.

> `ParentA`--> `ChildA`-->`GrandChildA`.

So if you create object of GrandChildA, then first function of GrandChildA get called.

> `general`-->`general.specific`-->`general.specific.more_specific`

Similarly in Hierarchical Order `general.specific.more_specific` called first, then `general.specific`, then `general`.
And the function may modify the keyword arguments passed to that function or return a value, that will entually becomes the sequence of execution.

Coming back to your example of S3, it will become something like,

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='mybucket')
```

If you always want to default your bucket name to my bucket, you could do it by doing,

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

event_system = s3.meta.events

def add_my_bucket(params, **kwargs):
    if 'Bucket' not in params:
        params['Bucket'] = 'mybucket'
```